# defining ImageView width relative to parent view's width?

Tags: android

I have a layout below like this

```
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="some text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_main"
        android:layout_width="???"
        android:layout_height="???"           
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"        
        android:src="@drawable/ic_computer" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="some text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The title text should stick to the top of layout, image in the centre and button at the bottom.

I want to set the width and height of the ImageView to be 50% of the width of its parent.
Any ideas how this can be achieved here ?

Comment: Maybe use a LinearLayout instead? You can achieve what you want, and there's nothing (at least in this xml) that requires a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is no way you can re-size your image in half of the parent's width and hieght in `relativeLayout` but in `linearlayout` you can do it easily by layout weight.

If you want to do it in `relativelayout` you can create your own CustomImageView class that extends ImageView and override the `onMeasure` method of the ImageView from there you can then set your width that you desire which is 50%

**example:**

```
    public class ImageViewHalfWidth extends ImageView {

    public ImageViewPefectSquare(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ImageViewPefectSquare(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ImageViewPefectSquare(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int measuredWidthHalf = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(),
            widthMeasureSpec) / 2; //50% of the width of its parent
        int measuredHeightHalf = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(),
            heightMeasureSpec) / 2; //50% of the Height of its parent
        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidthHalf, measuredHeightHalf);
    }

}
```

**To use it in xml**

```
 <com.yourpackage.ImageViewHalfWidth
    android:id="@+id/imageView_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"           
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"        
    android:src="@drawable/ic_computer" />
```

Comment: I have tried your code, the end result does not look like 50% instead 25% or so, the values in widthMeasureSpec and heightMeasureSpec appear to be some large numbers (1073742904 etc) and sometimes -ve as well..

Comment: Great, it worked :) but I am not sure about the logic here, an explanation of that part would certainly help ..Thanks

Comment: @Ahmed the getDefaultSize will Returns
The size this view should be according to parent view.